# characteristics of auditory hallucinations

Tags: schizophrenia, auditory-discrimination

How common is it for someone suffering from auditory hallucinations to recognize the voice(s) as someone they know, whether it be a direct or indirect relationship?  By direct I mean someone they personally have acquaintance with, and by indirect someone they recognize, such as a TV personality, but do not formally have relation with.  When I say common, I mean normal phenomena.

Comment: In my experience as a psychiatrist I would say it’s quite uncommon, but not rare. Perhaps somewhere around 1 in 20 patients with auditory hallucinations or so would be my guess.

Comment: @JonB are you implying most voice-hearers are dealing with generic phenomena?  If so, those phenomena must still possess certain characteristics, eg, soft, loud, harsh, male, female, etc...and also, those qualities affect the delusion, in addition to the semantics?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by generic. It seems to me that most voice hearers who are at a psychotic level ascribes the voices to persons or entitoes that don’t exist, or they’re uncertain about whose voices they hear.